# Why does boost::future<T>::then() spawn a new thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost

When attaching a continuation to `boost::future`, the continuation is executed in a new thread:

```
std::cout << "main: " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

boost::promise<void> p;
boost::future<void> f = p.get_future();
p.set_value();

boost::future<void> f2 = f.then([] (boost::future<void>) {
    std::cout << "future: " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;        
});
```

This snippet outputs:

```
main: 0x7fff7a8d7310
future: 0x101781000
```

Why is `.then()` allowed to do that, and, more importantly, is there a way to customise this behaviour? Do `future`s returned from `promise`/`packaged_task`/`async` behave differently?

Comment: .then() is like async() in that respect, I suppose. And yes there are subtle differences between futures returned from async vs. the ones directly gotten from a promise (or packaged_task). I think it was Scott Meyer who described this in most detail (and actually considers it a bad property of the current standard). There should also be boost::launch::deferred/async parameters there, like with async

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is already mentioned in @ikh answer. But to make it more clear, here is the direct answer to the OP question.

It is customizable whether `boost::future` continuation should be executed in a new thread or in the calling thread.

`boost::launch` policy parameter specifies how the continuation should run. See here: [Enumeration launch](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.launch)

```
enum class launch
{
    none = unspecified,
    async = unspecified,
    deferred = unspecified,
    executor = unspecified,
    inherit = unspecified,
    any = async | deferred
};
```

> A future created by `async(launch::deferred, ...)` or `::then(launch::deferred, ...)` has associated a launch policy `launch::deferred`.

So, try running this:

```
boost::future<void> f2 = f.then(
    boost::launch::deferred,
    [] (boost::future<void>&&) {
        std::cout << "future: " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;        
    }
);
```

That should run the continuation in the same thread.
Tested with boost 1.61 + Visual Studio 2015 on Windows platform.

Comment: How would I make continuations run on the same thread **by default** (globally) without adding this launch policy thing to each and every invocation?

Comment: I'm doing that by writing the simple wrapper around `boost::future`. It decorates `boost::future::then()` method call with explicit passing `boost::launch::deferred` policy.

Comment: Ok, I see. I am maintaining a library, and doing what you suggest would mean all users of the library have to use the wrapped future thing, not the plain boost one. This also isn't pretty. Anyway, could you post your wrapper somewhere? Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score -3):

It is reasonable to spawn a new thread.. Look at this code:

```
std::cout << "main: " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

boost::promise<void> p;
boost::future<void> f = p.get_future();
p.set_value();

boost::future<void> f2 = f.then([] (boost::future<void>) {
    SomeVeryVeryVeryLongLongLongLongTask();

    std::cout << "future: " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;        
});
```

Without spawning a new thread, we have to wait for `SomeVeryVeryVeryLongLongLongLongTask()` at `f.then(...`.

---

If you want to see certain evidence? In [reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.unique_future.then),

- If the parent was created with promise<< or with a packaged_task<> (has no associated launch policy), the continuation behaves the same as the third overload with a policy argument of launch::async | launch::deferred and the same argument for func.

As you know, if we use `launch::async | launch::deferred`, we don't know whether a new thread is spawned or just it's deferred. But mostly a new thread is spawned, right?

PS. Um? reference say "...promise<<...". Maybe it's a mistype of `promise<>` >o<

PS2. see @sehe's replies. Strictly speaking, he's right.

Comment: That's just defining it so. The continuation could be made to execute on the same thread as the preceding task. Spawning a thread is less expected and has downsides. In general I think the question comes down to: _does boost async/then allow control over thread scheduling?_ (Your answer doesn't address that)

Comment: Aw. That edit is very useful. But that last bit "But mostly a new thread is spawned, right?" unnecessarily kills the objectivity value. But yeah, this spells: you can't control thread scheduling here.

Comment: @sehe Strictly speaking, you're right. But I want to go easily... Regardless of whether a new thread is spawned or just task is run on another thread, it has a similar effect..

Comment: except if you can control the number of threads/scheduling. Imagine a `boost::async::set_thread_pool_size(1)`

Comment: @sehe Oops, I couldn't think that >o<, but let's go easily... that case rarely happens.

Comment: I don't think the OP is after statistics or probabilities.

Comment: Running each continuation on a new thread is neither reasonable nor required when the stuff being run is IO bound - this is the whole point of async programming.